# Trying to validate two different format in one regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I want to validate these formats in one regular expression in asp.net:

XX-XXXXXXX or XXX-XX-XXXX

These have to be numeric only no characters except the "-".

Is this possible?  I've been trying without any success so I want to ask the experts.

Thanks,
Pune

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work given your requirements.

```
"(^\d{2}-\d{7}$)|(^\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$)"
```

Comment: perfect!! Thank You!

Comment: If it solved your problem please mark it as an answer so future people can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try something [like this](http://www.regexpal.com/?fam=98163):

```
/^([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{7}|[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})$/
```

- `[0-9]` means any character from 0 to 9.
- `{X}` means X times
- `|` means "or"
- `-` means "-"
- and `(` and `)` delimits a group for replacing
- `^` and `$` delimit the beginning and the ending of the match.

Comment: Thanks Jaumzera but that didn't work...

Comment: I didn't realize that you said about X being numbers.

Comment: I updated the regex and the link as well.

Comment: Awesome thank you!!

Comment: This actually doesn't work correctly as it will say the value "00-00-00-0000" matches. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/r2VcdB.

Comment: You've got the reason. Of course it must be put between ^ and $.